# Why do empty quotes result in different output that nothing?

Tags: command-line, apt, server, bash

When I run either of the following in the terminal:

```
''
```

```
""
```

I get the following output:

```
Command '' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install libpam-mount      
sudo apt install openssh-server    
sudo apt install openvswitch-common
sudo apt install openvswitch-switch
sudo apt install php-common        
sudo apt install bpfcc-tools       
sudo apt install mailutils-mh      
sudo apt install mmh               
sudo apt install nmh
```

But, when I just press enter, nothing happens. Shouldn't these two cases have the same output of nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press enter it's just an empty line (zero tokens). When you  enter `''` there is a`''` token (even if it is an empty string) so something tries to execute it(*). On my 16.04:

```
>>>''
: command not found
```

You can also try to execute space:

```
>>>' '
 : command not found
```

So the package suggestion mechanism is a bit buggy on your distro.

(*) Also, compare plain `ls` vs `ls ''`